# How can I load Google Analytics Files that were extracted before billing was enabled to Big Query after billing is enabled?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I set up my link from Google Analytics to Big Query several weeks ago.  I was not able to add billing information until today.  How can I get Biq Query to load the files that were extracted these past couple of weeks before billing was enabled?  Alternatively is there a way to extract data from before a link was set up?

Thanks!
Kristin

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to extract Google Analytics data to BigQuery from before setting up the linking.